# Calculating scaled score using Item Response Theory (IRT, 3PL) in R with MIRT package

Tags: r

I have an English Listening Comprehension test consisting of 50 items taken by about 400 students. I would like to score the test using the TOEFL scale (31-68), and it is claimed that TOEFL is scored using IRT (3PL model). I am using MIRT package in R to obtain three parameters, as I used 3PL model.

```
library(readxl)

TOEFL006 <- read_excel("TOEFL Prediction Mei 2021 Form 006.xlsx")
TOEFL006_LIST <- TOEFL006[, 9:58]

library(mirt)

sv <- mirt(TOEFL006_LIST,                # data frame (ordinal only)
       1,                                # 1 for unidimentional, 2 for exploratory 
       itemtype = '3PL')                 # models, i.e. Rasch, 1PL, 2PL, and 3PL

sv_coeffs <- coef(sv,
              simplify = T,
              IRTpars = T)

sv_coeffs
```

The result is shown below :

|  | a | b | g | u |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| L1 | 2.198 | 0.165 | 0.198 | 1 |
| L2 | 2.254 | 0.117 | 0.248 | 1 |
| L3 | 2.103 | -0.049 | 0.232 | 1 |
| L4 | 4.663 | 0.293 | 0.248 | 1 |
| L5 | 1.612 | -0.374 | 0.001 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Then I calculated the factor score using the following codes:

```
factor_score <- fscores(sv, method = "EAP", full.scores = T)
```

The first five results are shown below:

```
head(factor_score)

[1,]  2.1839888
[2,]  1.8886260
[3,]  0.6791995
[4,]  1.2761837
[5,]  0.8195919
[6,] -1.5257231
```

The problem is that I do not know how to convert the factor score into the TOEFL score of 31 - 68 (as shown on the ETS website for listening score: https://www.ets.org/s/toefl_itp/pdf/38781-TOEFL-itp-flyer_Level1_HR.pdf).

Would anyone help me show how I can do that in R, please? Or maybe there are other ways of obtaining students' scores. Your help is much appreciated.

The data can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WwwjzgxJRBByCXAjdlNkGNRCtXjMlddW/view?usp=sharing

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate each respondents ability score use:

`Theta <- fscores(mod, method = 'MAP', itemtype = '2-PL', stats.only = TRUE) head(personfit(mod, Theta=Theta))`

Working through a similar project and found it in the mirt help files :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood something. It doesn't seem to be scored using IRT - [according to wikipedia, it's just summed up, which is a quite normal way to score tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_of_English_as_a_Foreign_Language#:%7E:text=The%20TOEFL%20iBT%20test%20is,to%20determine%20the%20total%20score.). Maybe I misunderstood it, but if it's done like you say, I think it uses a proprietary scoring model and you should likely contact and pay them to get you your scores.

So to get the scores, you would simply do `TOEFL006_LIST$total <- RowSums(TOEFL006_LIST)` and get the head using `head(TOEFL006_LIST$total)`.

Also, I'm glad not to be a student of yours - you're putting their names out in the open in your linked dataset... If you're in Europe it would be illegal, possibly in other countries too.

Comment: Ah. How could I miss that. Thanks for pointing that out. I have deleted the student detail. Pursuant to your explanation, it seems it is not the sum score because there are only 50 questions, but the maximum score is 68. The ETS clearly states that they use 3PL model to score the test. I still hope there is a way to convert it to the TOEFL scaled score.

Comment: It seems like a difficult thing to do. It seems the method is proprietary. You could try just scaling the scores to make them fit, by means of multiplication for example. It won't be valid internationally without paying toefl though.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to your question and I found that you can use this function to get a homologous score from a given `model` and `theta` value.

```
expected.test(model, as.matrix(theta))
```

`theta` should be specifically a matrix.